# Async tcp sever memory keeps on growing and also getting 10054 error on endreceive sometime

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp

In addition to memory usage increase at an alarming rate, I am also getting "An existing connection was closed by remote host 10054" at end receive and pgm stops. Please help
Thanks

I have a TCP socket server and it works fine . But the working memory grows from  10 MB to 250 MB.

I monitored nestat for any closed_wait sockets, but did not find any?

Can anybody please help me. It must handle many connections with no memory leak.

Code for StartListen

```
void StartListen(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string portStr = textBoxPort.Text;
        int port = System.Convert.ToInt32(portStr);
        // Create the listening socket...
        m_mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream,
            ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

        m_mainSocket.Bind(ipLocal);

        m_mainSocket.Listen(100);

        m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect),null);

        UpdateControls(true);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        writer.WriteToLog("In StartListen " + se.Message);
    }
}

public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    try
    {
        Socket m_mainSocket = (Socket)asyn.AsyncState;

        Socket workerSocket = m_mainSocket.EndAccept(asyn);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref m_clientCount);

        m_workerSocketList.Add(workerSocket);

        WaitForData(workerSocket, m_clientCount);

        m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed\n");
    }
    catch (Exception se)
    {
        writer.WriteToLog(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " OnClientConnect " + se.Message);
    }
}

public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    // Logger.Log("In OnDataReceived");
    SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
    bool socketClosed = false;


    try
    {
        // Complete the BeginReceive() asynchronous call by EndReceive() method
        // which will return the number of characters written to the stream 
        // by the client
        int iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
        char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
        // Extract the characters as a buffer
        System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer,
            0, iRx, chars, 0);




        System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
            szData= szData.TrimEnd('\0');




             if (!SocketExtensions.IsConnected(socketData.m_currentSocket)) {

            socketData.m_currentSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            socketData.m_currentSocket.Close();
                              return;
               } 

        else
        {

            WaitForData(socketData.m_currentSocket, socketData.m_clientNumber);
        }
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        if (se.ErrorCode == 10054) // Error code for Connection reset by peer
        {
            string msg = "Client " + socketData.m_clientNumber + " Disconnected" + "\n";

            // Remove the reference to the worker socket of the closed client
            // so that this object will get garbage collected
            m_workerSocketList[socketData.m_clientNumber - 1] = null;
            UpdateClientListControl();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
           // Logger.Log(se.Message);
            writer.WriteToLog("OnDataReceived " + se.Message);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // Logger.Log(ex.Message);
        writer.WriteToLog("OnDataReceived " + ex.Message);
    }
}
static class SocketExtensions
{
    public static bool IsConnected(this Socket socket)
    {
        try
        { 
            return !(socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0);
        }
        catch (SocketException) { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Memory growing? How did you measure that?

Comment: The memory keeps on growing from 20 MB to 900 MB in 1 and half days

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with the memory footprint of a .NET app growing to a certain size, as long as it doesn't *keep on* growing. Depending on the work load, your TCP server allocates many objects everytime it accepts new clients, and sends/receives data. Even after they are no longer used, these objects stay in memory for a while until GC releases them. This doesn't mean there is a memory-leak.

If the memory usage is growing so much that you're running into system memory problems, make sure you're not somehow keeping around some objects created while handling client requests.

Comment: The exe memory usage is increasing steadily and after  a 24 hour run there was an big increase . I monitored using task manager.  have  OnDataReceived method where I am closing sockets

Comment: Task Manager is not an effective way of testing memory usage. Get a real memory profiler and use that.

Comment: @user180175 Still depends on what you mean by "big increase". Are you running into system memory problems? If not, then maybe you shouldn't worry about the increase. If you really think the memory usage is increasing abnormally, you'll need to investigate using a profiler, e.g. VS [Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264934.aspx) (only in premium and ultimate editions).

Comment: The exe memory has gone from 10 MB to 350 MB increase in the past 12 hours.

Comment: That doesn't sound _too_ bad. For optimal performance, GC may choose to keep more memory around (by not releasing memory). There's nothing in the code you provided that jumps out as trouble. (side note, you don't need that `IsConnected` extension method -- if `EndReceive` returns 0, that means the connection was closed.)

Comment: Thanks. But this sever has to run forever. The number of clients will continue to increase and I am worried about this